# Not able to redirect to payment page

Tags: php, html, jquery

The below code was created by some developer, after changing the web hosting the redirection to payment gateway is not happening. checked all the missing files while migrating everything found  correct. I am not a php developer, not able to understand why its not working. Below is the code.

```
<!-- Payment Sending -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#payment-form").on("submit",function(e){
e.preventDefault();
if($("#payment-form [name='customerid']").val() === '')
{
$("#payment-form [name='customerid']");
}
else if ($("#payment-form [name='productname']").val() === '')
{
$("#payment-form [name='productname']");
}
else if ($("#payment-form [name='productsize']").val() === '')
{
$("#payment-form [name='productsize']");
}
else if ($("#payment-form [name='productprice']").val() === '')
{
$("#payment-form [name='productprice']");
}
else if ($("#payment-form [name='name']").val() === '')
{
$("#payment-form [name='name']").css("border","1px solid red");
}
else if ($("#payment-form [name='email']").val() === '')
{
$("#payment-form [name='email']").css("border","1px solid red");
}
else if ($("#payment-form [name='phone']").val() === '')
{
$("#payment-form [name='phone']").css("border","1px solid red");
}
else
{
$("#loading-img").css("display","block");
var sendData = $( this ).serialize();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "get_response.php",
data: sendData,
dataType: "json",
success: function(data){
    if(data.status == 'success'){
        console.log('submitted');
        $("#loading-img").css("display","none");
        window.location.href="/payment/payment.php?customerid="+data.customerId;
    }else if(data.status == 'error'){
        $("#loading-img").css("display","none");
        $(".response_msg").text(data.errormsg);
        $(".response_msg").slideDown().fadeOut(9000);
        $("#payment-form").find("input[type=text], input[type=email], textarea").val("");
    }
}
 
});
}
});
 
$("#payment-form input").blur(function(){
var checkValue = $(this).val();
if(checkValue != '')
{
$(this).css("border","1px solid #eeeeee");
}
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: It's hard to say what is the problem without PHP error response. As far as I can see, the form should be send properly in case all fields are not empty https://jsfiddle.net/vyspiansky/p9ngqz0c/ Using real code open a browser console > Network, then submit the form and check response from `get_response.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

If all files are in the same place as before it could be the PHP version check on Cpanel or execute a phpinfo(); on a clean php file to get that info and compare it to the old hosting.

I can see some error handling, does the page render something when you try to go to payment. Hope the PHP version works, if not you can check the php.ini config and modules activated on both hosting. That configs are always a problem when you go from local to hosting or hosting to hosting.

Best Regards, I will be following this to help you.

Comment: Hi Javier,  Thanks for your quick response, both the hosting on the same note, but the new hosting is on 7.4 but old hosting was on 7.3 version.  I could see only to modules enabled on the old hosting php.ini. allow_url_fopen and file_uploads.

Comment: You should change the new host to 7.3, maybe there is some deprecated functions, and enable those modules too and test.

Comment: shifted to 7.3 no lucj